# Windows Store load URL image and get size

Tags: windows, dimensions, bitmapimage

I need to load 8 images into Image or BitmapImage elements in my C# Windows Store (Windows RT) app, and need to find their dimensions (even before they are being displayed). I can download the images, but can't really figure out how to get the size (size is always zero). The reason size is zero is that the bitmap image has not loaded, but can't figure out how to wait till the image is loaded, catch the function that indicates image has loaded.

Here is the key code, where the `ImageOpened` or `ImageFailed` never get called:

```
bm.ImageOpened += bm_ImageOpened;
bm.ImageFailed += bm_ImageFailed;
bm = new BitmapImage(new Uri(arbitraryImageUriThatKeepsChanging, UriKind.Absolute));
image.ImageFailed += image_ImageFailed;
image.ImageOpened += image_ImageOpened;
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(arbitraryImageUriThatKeepsChanging, 
               UriKind.Absolute)); 
/* .. at this point the image still has not been loaded,
 so can't find the dimensions or if it failed or not, and the functions to catch
 image opened and failed are never called..*/
```

All I need is to load images from external web site, and find the dimensions, before displaying the images.

Comment: Seems like you'd want to get the size or other info inside your image_ImageOpened method.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a dummy-`Image`element that is invisible to preload the image.

In your Xaml:

```
<Image Name="DummyImage" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

Code behind:

```
BitmapImage btm = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://anyurl.com/foo.jpg"));
btm.DownloadProgress += btm_DownloadProgress;
DummyImage.Source = btm;

private void btm_DownloadProgress(object sender, DownloadProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Progress == 100)
        {
            int width = ((BitmapImage)sender).PixelWidth;
        }
    }
```

You should be able to use either the DownloadProgress or the ImageLoaded event.